# Optimize the query of weekday statistics between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a table with two fields: `start_date` and `end_date`. Now I want to count the total number of work overtime. I have created a new calendar table to maintain the working day status of the date.

table: workdays

```
id                  status
2020-01-01          4
2020-01-02          1
2020-01-03          1
2020-01-04          2
```

4: holiday, 1: weekday, 2: weekend

I created a function to calculate the weekdays between two dates (excluding weekends, holidays).

```sql
create or replace function get_workday_count (start_date in date, end_date in date)
return number is
    day_count int;
begin
    select count(0) into day_count from WORKDAYS
    where TRUNC(ID) >= TRUNC(start_date)
    and TRUNC(ID) <= TRUNC(end_date)
    and status in (1, 3, 5);
    return day_count;
end;
```

When I execute the following query statement, it takes about 5 minutes to display the results, `erp_sj` table has about 200000 rows of data.

```sql
select count(0) from ERP_SJ GET_WORKDAY_COUNT(start_date, end_date) > 5;
```

The fields used in query statements are indexed.

How to optimize? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Out of interest, why `count(0)` and not the standard expression?

Comment: Can you share the index details and the execution plan? Probably the index can't be used because of the `trunc`, which doesn't seem necessary. How many of `workdays.id` values have a time component that isn't `00:00:00`?

Comment: What's your oracle version? Is it 12+?

Comment: What are day types 3 and 5, and how many of them are there in `ERP_SJ`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, optimizing your function:
1.adding pragma udf (for faster execution in sql
2. Adding deterministic clause(for caching)
3. Replacing count(0) to count(*) (to allow cbo optimize count)
4. Replacing return number to int

```sql
create or replace function get_workday_count (start_date in date, end_date in date)
return int deterministic is
    pragma udf;
   day_count int;
begin
    select count(*) into day_count from WORKDAYS w
    where w.ID >= TRUNC(start_date)
    and w.ID <= TRUNC(end_date)
    and status in (1, 3, 5);
    return day_count;
end;
```

Then you don't need to call your function in case of (end_date - start_date) < required number of days. Moreover, ideally it would be to use scalar subquery instead of function:

```sql
select count(*) 
from ERP_SJ 
where 
case 
   when trunc(end_date) - trunc(start_date) > 5 
      then GET_WORKDAY_COUNT(trunc(start_date) , trunc(end_date)) 
   else 0
 end > 5
```

Or using subquery:

```sql
select count(*) 
from ERP_SJ e
where 
case 
   when trunc(end_date) - trunc(start_date) > 5 
      then (select count(*) from WORKDAYS w
    where w.ID >= TRUNC(e.start_date)
    and w.ID <= TRUNC(e.end_date)
    and w.status in (1, 3, 5)) 
   else 0
 end > 5
```

Answer (score 2):

**WORKDAY_STATUSES table** (just for completeness, not used below):

```
create table workday_statuses
( status number(1) constraint workday_statuses_pk primary key
, status_name varchar2(10) not null constraint workday_status_name_uk unique );

insert all
    into workday_statuses values (1, 'Weekday')
    into workday_statuses values (2, 'Weekend')
    into workday_statuses values (3, 'Unknown 1')
    into workday_statuses values (4, 'Holiday')
    into workday_statuses values (5, 'Unknown 2')
select * from dual;
```

**WORKDAYS table**: one row for each day in 2020:

```
create table workdays
( id date constraint workdays_pk primary key 
, status references workday_statuses not null )
organization index;

insert into workdays (id, status)
select date '2019-12-31' + rownum
     , case
           when to_char(date '2019-12-31' + rownum, 'Dy', 'nls_language = English') like 'S%' then 2
           when date '2019-12-31' + rownum in
                ( date '2020-01-01', date '2020-04-10', date '2020-04-13'
                , date '2020-05-08', date '2020-05-25', date '2020-08-31'
                , date '2020-12-25', date '2020-12-26', date '2020-12-28' ) then 4
           else 1
       end
from   xmltable('1 to 366')
where  date '2019-12-31' + rownum < date '2021-01-01';
```

**ERP_SJ table** containing 30K rows with random data:

```
create table erp_sj
( id          integer generated always as identity
, start_date  date not null
, end_date    date not null
, filler      varchar2(100) );

insert into erp_sj (start_date, end_date, filler)
select dt, dt + dbms_random.value(0,7), dbms_random.string('x',100)
from   ( select date '2019-12-31' + dbms_random.value(1,366) as dt
         from   xmltable('1 to 30000') );

commit;
```

**get_workday_count() function:**

```
create or replace function get_workday_count
    ( start_date in date, end_date in date )
    return integer
    deterministic    -- Cache some results
    parallel_enable  -- In case you want to use it in parallel queries
as
    pragma udf;      -- Tell compiler to optimise for SQL
    day_count integer;
begin
    select count(*) into day_count
    from   workdays w
    where  w.id between trunc(start_date) and end_date
    and    w.status in (1, 3, 5);

    return day_count;
end;
```

Notice that you should not truncate `w.id`, because all values have the time as `00:00:00` already. (I'm assuming that if `end_date` falls somewhere in the middle of a day, you want to count that day, so I have not truncated the `end_date` parameter.)

Test:

```
select count(*) from erp_sj
where  get_workday_count(start_date, end_date) > 5;

COUNT(*)
--------
    1302
```

Results returned in around 1.4 seconds.

Execution plan for the query within the function:

```
select count(*)
from   workdays w
where  w.id between trunc(sysdate) and sysdate +10
and    w.status in (1, 3, 5);

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name        | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |             |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |             |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
|*  2 |   FILTER           |             |      1 |        |      7 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| WORKDAYS_PK |      1 |      7 |      7 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now try adding the function as a virtual column and indexing it:

```
create index erp_sj_workday_count_ix on erp_sj(workday_count);

select count(*) from erp_sj
where  workday_count > 5;
```

Same result in 0.035 seconds. Plan:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name                    | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                         |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE   |                         |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| ERP_SJ_WORKDAY_COUNT_IX |      1 |   1302 |   1302 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tested in 19.0.0.

**Edit:** As Sayan pointed out, the index on the virtual column won't be automatically updated if there are any changes in `WORKDAYS`, so there is a risk of wrong results with this approach. However, if performance is critical you could work around it by rebuilding the index on `ERP_SJ` every time you updated `WORKDAYS`. Maybe you could do this in a statement-level trigger on `WORKDAYS`, or just through scheduled IT maintenance processes if updates are very infrequent and `ERP_SJ` isn't so big that an index rebuild is impractical. If the index is partitioned, rebuilding affected partitions could be an option.

Or, don't have an index and live with the 1.4 seconds query execution time.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to add virtual column and create index on it based on the function that depends on the data in another table. Oracle doesn't sync FBI with the changes in that table.

Comment: It's not a FBI though, it's an index on a VC. I just ran `update erp_sj set end_date = start_date;` and the count correctly returns 0.

Comment: I mean `workdays` table, which is used in the function `get_workday_count`. Try to delete rows from workdays.

Comment: index on VC is functionally an FBI really :)

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. You have to rebuild the index. Thanks :)

Comment: + 1 for the *new feature of the day* `xmltable (1 to N)` but generally I do not prefere this approach. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the columns `ID` and `status` have indexes on them ( not functional index on `TRUNC(ID)` ). So use this query

```
SELECT count(0)
  INTO day_count
  FROM WORKDAYS
 WHERE ID BETWEEN TRUNC(start_date) AND TRUNC(end_date)
   AND status in (1, 3, 5);
```

in order to be able to exploit the index on date column `ID` also.

Answer (score 1):

May be try [Scalar Subquery Caching](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/efficient-function-calls-from-sql)

(in case there are plenty `erp_sj` records with the same `start_date` and `end_date`)

```
select count(0) from ERP_SJ where
 (select GET_WORKDAY_COUNT(start_date, end_date) from dual) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a *data warehouse* query (not an OLTP query).

Some best practices says you should

1. **get rid od functions** - avoid contenxt switch (this could be somehow mitigated with the `UDF pragma` but why to use function if you don't need it?)
2. **get rid of indexes** - quick for few rows; slow for large number of records
3. **get rid of caching** - caching is basically a workaround for repeating same thing

So the *data warehouse approach* for the problem consists of two steps

**Extend the Workday Table**

The workday table can be with a little query extended with a new column `MIN_END_DAY` that defines for each (start) day the minimum threshold to reach the limit of 5 working days.

The query uses `LEAD` aggregate function to get the 4th leading working day (check the `PARTITION BY` clause that distincs between the working ays and other days.

For the non working days you simple takes the `LAST_VALUE` of the next working day.

Example

```
with wd as (
select ID, STATUS,
case when status in (1, 3, 5) then
lead(id,4) over (partition by case when status in (1, 3, 5) then 'workday' end order by id)  /* 4 working days ahead */
end as min_stop_day
from workdays),
wd2 as (
select ID, STATUS, 
last_value(MIN_STOP_DAY) ignore nulls over (order by id desc) MIN_END_DAY
from wd)
select ID, STATUS, MIN_END_DAY 
from wd2
order by 1;

ID,             STATUS, MIN_END_DAY
01.01.2020 00:00:00 4   08.01.2020 00:00:00
02.01.2020 00:00:00 1   08.01.2020 00:00:00
03.01.2020 00:00:00 1   09.01.2020 00:00:00
04.01.2020 00:00:00 2   10.01.2020 00:00:00
05.01.2020 00:00:00 2   10.01.2020 00:00:00
06.01.2020 00:00:00 1   10.01.2020 00:00:00
```

**Join to the Base Table**

Now you can simple join your base table with the the extended `workday` table on the `start_day` and filter rows by comparing the `end_day`with the `MIN_END_DAY`

Query

```
with wd as (
select ID, STATUS,
case when status in (1, 3, 5) then
lead(id,4) over (partition by case when status in (1, 3, 5) then 'workday' end order by id) 
end as min_stop_day
from workdays),
wd2 as (
select ID, STATUS, 
last_value(MIN_STOP_DAY) ignore nulls over (order by id desc) MIN_END_DAY
from wd)
select count(*) from erp_sj 
join wd2
on trunc(erp_sj.start_date) = wd2.ID
where trunc(end_day) >= min_end_day
```

This will lead for large tables to the expected `HASH JOIN` execution plan.

Note that I assume 1) the workday table is complete (otherwise you can't use inner join) and 2) contains enough future data (the last 5 rows are obviously not usable).